# Why this externa web service call go into error only when the call is performed using Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, resttemplate, spring-rest

I am working on a Spring project implementing a simple console application that have to call an external REST web service passing to it a parameter and obtaining a response from it.

The call to this webservice is:

```
http://5.249.148.180:8280/GLIS_Registration/6
```

where **6** is the specified **ID**. If you open this address in the browser (or by **cURL** tool) you will obtain the expected error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <sampleid>IRGC 100000</sampleid>
    <genus>Oryza</genus>
    <error>PGRFA sampleid [IRGC 100000], genus [Oryza] already registered for this owner</error>
</response>
```

This error message is the expected response for this request and I correctly obtain it also using **cURL** tool to perform the request.

So I have to perform this GET request from my Spring application.

To do it I create this **getResponse()** method into a **RestClient** class:

```
@Service
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class RestClient {

    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    String uriResourceRegistrationApi;

    public RestClient() {
        super();

        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        uriResourceRegistrationApi = "http://5.249.148.180:8280/GLIS_Registration/7";
    }

    public ResponseEntity<String> getResponse() {

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uriResourceRegistrationApi, String.class);
        return response;

    }
}
```

Then I call this method from this test method:

```
@Test
public void singleResourceRestTest() {
    System.out.println("singleResourceRestTest() START");

    ResponseEntity<String> result = restClient.getResponse();

    System.out.println("singleResourceRestTest() END");
}
```

But I am experiencing a very strange behavior, what it happens is:

1)The call to my external web service seems that happens (I saw it from the web services log).

2) The web service retrieve the parameter having value **7** but then it seems that can't use it as done without problem performing the request from the browser or by the shell statment:

```
curl -v http://5.249.148.180:8280/GLIS_Registration/7
```

But now, calling in this way, my webservice (I can't post the code because it is a WSO2 ESB flow) give me this error message:

```
<200 OK,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <error>Location information not correct</error>
    <error>At least one between &lt;genus> and &lt;cropname> is required</error>
    <error>Sample ID is required</error>
    <error>Date is required</error>
    <error>Creation method is required</error>
</response>,{Vary=[Accept-Encoding], Content-Type=[text/html; charset=UTF-8], Date=[Fri, 05 May 2017 14:07:09 GMT], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Connection=[keep-alive]}>
```

Looking the web service log it seems that performing the call using **RestTemplate** it have some problem to use the retrieved **ID=7** to perform a database query.

I know it looks terribly strange and you can see: "The problem is of your web service and not of the Spring RestTemplate". This is only partially true because I implemented this custom method that perform a low level Http GET call, this **callWsOldStyle()** (putted into the previous **RestClient** class):

```
public void callWsOldStyle() {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        URL restAPIUrl = new URL("http://5.249.148.180:8280/GLIS_Registration/7");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) restAPIUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        // Read the response
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder jsonData = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            jsonData.append(line);
        }


        System.out.println(jsonData.toString());
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
    // Clean up
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(reader);
        if(connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Using this method instead the RestTemplate one it works fine and this line:

```
System.out.println(jsonData.toString());
```

print the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><sampleid>IRGC 100005</sampleid><genus>Oryza</genus><error>PGRFA sampleid [IRGC 100005], genus [Oryza] already registered for this owner</error></response>
```

To summarize:

- Calling my WS from the browser it works.
- Calling my WS using cURL it works.
- Calling my WS using my **callWsOldStyle()** method it works.
- Calling my WS using the method that use **RestTemplate** it go into error when my WS receive and try to handle the request.

So, what can be the cause of this issue? What am I missing? Maybe can depend by some wrong header or something like this?

Comment: The point of RestTemplate is also to allow mapping to any class.
Since it appears you are receiving a Location, try parsing to Location instead of String.

Comment: @Lewis_McReu what do you exactly mean?

Comment: Currently you have this:
`ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(uriResourceRegistrationApi, String.class)`

Instead of String, use a class that has variables corresponding to those in the received xml.

Comment: Please check the response status for that API(`http://5.249.148.180:8280/GLIS_Registration/6`), It returns HTTP 500- Internal Server Error. I think `RestTemplate` will assign response only for HTTP 2xx. If the status is not 2xx it'll throw exception

Answer (score 0):

As Pete said you are receiving an internal server error (status code 500) so you should check the server side of this rest service.

In any case you can do the following for the `resttemplate`

- create an `org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback` object if
  you need to do something in the request
- create an `org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor<String>`
  object in order to extract your data
- use the resttemplate

**org.springframework.web.client.RequestCallback**

```
public class SampleRequestCallBack implements RequestCallback
{

    @Override
    public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException
    {
    }

}
```

**org.springframework.web.client.ResponseExtractor**

```
public class CustomResponseExtractor implements ResponseExtractor<String>
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomResponseExtractor.class.getName()); 
    @Override
    public String extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException
    {

        try
        {
            String result = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(response.getBody(), Charset.forName("UTF8"));
            if( logger.isInfoEnabled() )
            {
                logger.info("Response received.\nStatus code: {}\n Result: {}",response.getStatusCode().value(), result);
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**REST TEMPLATE CALL**

```
@Test
public void testStack()
{
    try
    {
        String url = "http://5.249.148.180:8280/GLIS_Registration/6";
        String response = restTemplate.execute(url, HttpMethod.GET, new SampleRequestCallBack(), new CustomResponseExtractor());;
        logger.info(response);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Errore", e);
    }
}
```

Angelo